# Having a main application that stores mini applications within the same app without install

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am looking into creating an application that will have the ability to for the user to use mini applications within the one app.

For example, if you have an application called `Main`, and another called `Book`. The user would open `Main` and then decide they want to click on `Book`. The `Book` application will load right in `Main` without having to install it.

If you dig deeper...

```
Main
|-> Book
|-> Videos
|-> Magizines

etc.
```

I can then do code changes to `Book`, upload the change, and it will automatically be in `Main`. The only application the user installs is `Main`.

Is something like this possible with React-Native? Without this being a simple yes/no question, in what direction should I be looking? I've seen CodeBase, but still unsure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly called a modular or plugin-based architecture. In react native you can consider using libraries like React Navigation

> React Navigation's native stack navigator provides a way for your app to transition between screens and manage navigation history

Here is docs and guidelines:
[https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation[enter](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation%5Benter) link description here][1](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation)

Also there are other ways to implemente this structure. While last approach is useful for updating JavaScript code without a full app update, for a more modular approach you can use this link which explains a Micro-Frontend architecture:
https://www.callstack.com/blog/step-by-step-guide-to-super-app-development